# create multidimension array from values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to create MD array from numbers like below to send as JSON

```
OrderStatus  Counts
Shipped      3

Pending      5
```

Final output should be,

```
[{order_status: "Shipped", Counts: 3}, {order_status: "Pending", Counts: 5} ]
```

Currently i am able to send only 1 row with this,

```
$orderTable[] = array(
                'order_status' => 'Shipped',
                'Counts' => 3);
```

How can i send two values as Json array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your array like this:

```
$orderTable = [ 
   [
      'order_status' => 'Shipped',
      'Counts' => 3
   ],
   [
      'order_status' => 'Pending',
      'Counts' => 5
   ]
];

$json = json_encode($orderTable);
```